# Testing ListView with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-listview, robolectric

I'm currently trying to test some Android Code with Robolectric but I'm having some issues with my ListView. When I try to access the a child view, ListView always return null, due to an empty List.

The implementation of the application looks like this and creates a simple list view:

```
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private static String values[] = 
        new String[] {"Android", "Apple", "Windows" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);

    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

However, when I'm trying to access my ListView as following. The Robolectric TestRunner always return null when I'm accessing the ArrayAdapter through getChildAt()

```
private OverviewActivity activity;
private ListView listView;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity = new OverviewActivity();      
    activity.onCreate(null);

    listView = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.tweet_list);
}

@Test
public void shouldFindListView() throws Exception {     
    if (listView.getChildCount() > 0) {
        assertThat(
                "Android",
                equalTo(listView.getChildAt(0).toString()));
    } else {
        fail("no child views are avaliable");
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is all your tests I wouldn't have it at all. What you're actually testing that Array has three elements and first element is "Android". One more comment - "if" condition could be replaced with assertEquals(3, listView.getChildCount())

Comment: What robolectric version do you use?

Comment: I'm using the Robolectric version 0.9.4. I'm currently trying to write my own ShadowArrayAdapter but having lot's of problems.

Comment: Didn't see the comment on their website that they're now distributing their resources through Sonatype. I was working with the old version which didn't supply ArrayAdapters ...

Comment: That's correct, I took a look to sources - everything is implemented. We are using Robolectric 1.2 here

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Answer (score 6):

If people like me, still visiting the link to resolve how to test listview with Roboelectric 3.0. This is my MAinActivityTest file

```
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private ListView lstView;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception{
    mainActivity= Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    assertNotNull("Mainactivity not intsantiated",mainActivity);
    lstView=(ListView)mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.list);//getting the list layout xml
    ShadowLog.stream = System.out; //This is for printing log messages in console
}

@Test
public void shouldFindListView()throws Exception{
    assertNotNull("ListView not found ", lstView);
    ShadowListView shadowListView = Shadows.shadowOf(lstView); //we need to shadow the list view

    shadowListView.populateItems();// will populate the adapter
    ShadowLog.d("Checking the first country name in adapter " ,
        ((RowModel)lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0)).getCountry());

    assertTrue("Country Japan doesnt exist", "Japan".equals(((RowModel) lstView.getAdapter().getItem(0)).getCountry()));
    assertTrue(3==lstView.getChildCount());
}
```

RowModel is the simple POJO for fields to be displayed in listview.

Comment: Yep, `ShadowListView.populateItems()` was the key. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using old version of Robolectric. We don't have any issues with similar code that yours with Robolectric 1.1.

So add this lines to your pom file:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Or download and bundle it to your project in your ide from here
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pivotallabs/robolectric/1.1